# What are the relevant rulings regarding being asked to leave my husband's house?

Tags: nikah, talaq

I got married 9 months ago, and there was several issues between me and my ex hubby, and the last one made him tell me to leave his house I told him I wasn’t leaving until he calls his walee on Friday, Saturday and finally on Sunday. I left. And I’ll be three months out of the house. I don't wish to go, but what does sharia rule?

Comment: would you please write your question in more formal form? In order to make it more creditable. God Bless You.

Comment: Assalamualaikum bro Seyyed, I got married Jan31st 2015, Went tru Sso mmucH but wanted to remain married, on 17tH July we had an isssue. Wit my Husband so He asked me to leave and I refused until 19th July. He pushed me out and threw my bag @ me, I rate dat as divorce

Comment: I presented an answer. But I recommend you to write your question more grammatical and with more precise details as much as possible in order to get a more correct answer. / َAnd read the conditions of divorce to be sure about what you are looking for. و من الله توفیق

Comment: Divorce must be uttered trowing you out of the house is exactly what a husband shouldn't do, as even if you are divorced you should stay in the house until the end of your 'iddah, as he is responsible for you and should be in charge of you until the talaq takes place and both of you become foreigners. See also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30388/are-women-who-are-divorced-after-the-consummation-entitled-to-maintenance/35793#35793

Answer (score -1):

```
                In the name of Allah, the most Gracious, the most Merciful
```

First of all, as I asked you at a comment, you’d better write your question in a more formal form (and more clear) with more details as much as possible. Anyhow, to the best of my knowledge and based on what I got from your explanation, it doesn’t seem to be considered as a correct talaq (divorce). Because there are some conditions for true talaq, such as the following condition which doesn’t seem to be done for you as what you explained:

> … if your husband divorces you of free will in the presence of two
>   just (Adil) witnesses, the divorce is valid.

---

In the meantime, it is not considered as a related factor of divorce as you said in your comment:

> He pushed me out and threw my bag

Eventually, I strongly recommend you to read the following references as related issues concerning divorce (its conditions) which can help you a lot (and God willing present you a more correct answer).

And Allah knows best

---

**References:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa8230)
- [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/a-new-perspective-women-islam-fatma-saleh-moustafa-al-qazwini/chapter-3-divorce-divorce-and-mahr)

Comment: I do ve witnesses, 2 pple.