# Is it impermissible to remarry your ex-husband unless you have married someone else?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

In researching an answer to [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43335/17163), I found this quote:

> It is not permissible to remarry your ex-husband unless you have married someone else. -- [muslim1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/17467/17163), 2014

I've seen this claim made repeatedly and up until now I thought it was correct.  However, I found this fatwa:

> If her waiting period ended from this second divorce, she is irrevocably divorced, and he cannot take her back except with a new dowry and a new marriage contract. -- [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=89845)

(And also another [IslamWeb fatwa](http://library.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=147013) regarding khula.)

It does not state the wife marrying someone else is a pre-condition of remarrying his ex-wife---they just get married again.  Hence my question:

**Question**: Is it impermissible to remarry your ex-husband unless you have married someone else?

Comment: It is true if she was divorced from him three times. Otherwise, she can remarry him directly. 

see
https://islamqa.info/en/140573

Comment: The statement of muslim1 is correct undder the given conditions:
Three talaqs have taken place the fatwa from IslamWeb covers the other option where a reconciliation was still possible, but missed during iddah also see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35851/when-is-it-possible-to-take-back-your-wife-after-divorce/35855#35855