# How does one go about getting an Islamic divorce in the USA?

Tags: talaq

When there has been an Islamic (but interfaith) marriage conducted, and it is found out later that the couple are unable to create a good marriage (i.e no common ground, no shared interests...nothing except for believing in our respective faiths), how does one get an Islamic divorce in the USA where the marriage was conducted?

Being in 2 different countries, it would make it difficult to fly over and do all the arrangements to meet with the officiator/imam. And what if the wife refuses to meet with the imam to conduct the divorce?

What is the Islamic way of doing this? What is the procedure? (Sunni)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Islam prescribes that you obey the laws of the land as long as they aren't forcing you to divert from Islam. If you want to marry a girl of the people of the book, you should marry her according to Islam and then register the marriage according to the laws of the United States.

If you then want to divorce her, pronounce "talaq" once (loudly in front of her) and that would be counted as a divorce according to Islam, then officially divorce her according to the laws of the United States.

Answer (score -4):

Well that will be counted as one Talaq as per Quran and Hadith. The Woman has to be separate from husband for 90 days and then TALAQ is done. But if they are united again then the TALAQ was not done as per ISLAMIC RULES.

Comment: This is wrong after a talaq the wife should stay with her husband until her 'iddah has ended as only then they are separated on foreigners. The woman leaving the house of her husband is a misconception and misinterpretation of the Qur'an [Are women who are divorced after the consummation entitled to maintenance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30388/are-women-who-are-divorced-after-the-consummation-entitled-to-maintenance). Beside this is not answering the question!