# What is the correct procedure for talaq regarding notifying the mosque, paperwork, and living arrangements?

Tags: talaq, non-muslim-countries

If a couple (interfaith) have been married both religiously (in Islam and civil courthouse in the west), what is the correct procedure for a Talaq?

Saying "I divorce you" x 3 essentially means in Islam that the couple are divorced. Is there anything else that needs to be done? Can the husband immediately move out or do they have to stay together for a period of time (but in separate rooms)?

Do they have to notify the mosque where they got the Nikah? Any Islamic paperwork needs to be done? Is there a time period where the husband has to wait to marry someone else?

Comment: How is this question different from [this one](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36025/how-does-one-go-about-getting-an-islamic-divorce-in-the-usa)?

Comment: Difference is quite clear :). In the question here I asked about living arrangements and if there is any other paperwork to be done. Some say yes, others no. Also giving talaq is not said once but thrice.

Comment: A islamically divorced woman must or should stay at the house of the husband until the end of her 'idah 3 times talaq means two previouse reconcilliations have happened but would a non-Muslim wife accept that?

Comment: Note for an islamic divorce it needs only one "talaq" with no reconcilliation. In case of a third talaq a remarrying would be impossible unless the wife marries somebody else.

Comment: Thanks. Well, unfortunately the relationship is a complete breakdown and to reconcile is not possible so the only way to make it right is to set each other free. Thus I am thinking that saying Talaq should be enough?