# How am I to face my husband after talaq before the 'Idah ends while a reconciliation is (theoretically) possible?

Tags: talaq, husband-wife, iddah

Two days ago my husband give me single talaq. I am still living in his house but we are avoiding each other he is not willing to ruju. what should I do ? do I immediately leave the house. leaving home is not possible immediately as my parents leaves in another country. that have some visa restriction. kindly guide me what should I do. what quran says to do.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. Leaving your husband's house before the end of the 'iddah is not shari'a conform if you don't fear any oppression it is even against it. See also [Are women who are divorced after consummation entitled to maintenance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30388/are-women-who-are-divorced-after-the-consummation-entitled-to-maintenance)

Comment: what should I do, do I follow my daily routines as I used to prepare the meal , taking care of children and doing house hold chores. How would I will face husband ? do I take purdah (a veil )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in my comments and in my answer on [Are women who are divorced after the consummation entitled to maintenance?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30388/are-women-who-are-divorced-after-the-consummation-entitled-to-maintenance?noredirect=1&lq=1) according to the Qur'an it is recommended for a wife who has been divorced a divorce with the option of reconciliation (rij'i) to stay at her husbands home at least till the end of the 'Iddah. And it is haram for a husband to throw his wife out of the house before her 'iddah has ended! Scholars even consider it similarly as a sin if she left without acceptable reasons, she can also come and go during this time. But she is asked to stay with him as long as she doesn't fear oppression etc. against what is often practiced and became a custom in many Muslim societies, where wives leave the husband's house at once when the husband utters talaq and move to their parents house, this is actually against the shari'a as widely explained and proved in the answer above.

Here some more evidences to support the claims above some more: In his commentary on verse ([65:1](http://legacy.quran.com/65/1)) imam al-Qurtobi said:

> “and turn them not out of their (husbands’) homes” means: the husband does not have the right to turn her out of the marital home so long as she is still observing ‘iddah, and it is not permissible for her either to leave, because of the husband’s rights, except in the case of clear necessity. If she leaves, she is sinning, but the ‘iddah is not interrupted. This applies equally to both revocably and irrevocably divorced women, and is ordained in order to protect the man’s sperm [from being confused with that of a subsequent husband, if the woman were to remarry soon and pregnant]. End quote.  (Source islamqa #[122703](https://islamqa.info/en/122703)

so the husband has still rights over his divorcee (by talaq) as long as her 'iddah has not yet ended. This leads to the conclusion that a woman can even still appear less covered and rouged in front of her husband during this time period, especially if she hopes to win him back and seeks reconciliation. But to be on the safer site she should avoid having intercourse without having him uttering -with witnessess- that he wants reconciliation (This is a matter on which scholars hold different opinions: some say having intercourse -initiated by the husband is per se a reconciliation others require the husband to announce the reconciliation first etc.).

> The point is that we must pay attention to this matter and remember that **the woman who is revocably divorced is obliged to remain in her husband’s house until the end of her ‘iddah. In this case, whilst she is staying in her husband’s house**, she may **uncover herself** in front of him, **adorn** herself, **beautify** herself, **put on perfume**, **speak** to him, and he may speak to her, and **she may sit with him** and do everything except intimacy or intercourse, which may only take place in the case of him taking her back. He may take her back verbally, so he may say, “I am taking back my wife”, or he may take her back by his actions, by having intercourse with her, with the intention of taking her back. End quote from Fataawa Islamiyyah. (Source same fatwa as above)

This shows that the daily life between spouses with the exception of intercourse can go forth during the time of 'iddah. But the woman should also make provisions for the case that the separation will be final and prepare and plan her moving out of the spousal house and plan her future. And also plan with her husband how to deal with the children in future. And if necessary seeking an intermediate to speak things out:

> And if you fear dissension between the two, send an arbitrator from his people and an arbitrator from her people. If they both desire reconciliation, Allah will cause it between them. Indeed, Allah is ever Knowing and Acquainted [with all things]. ([4:35](https://legacy.quran.com/4/35))